# Espresso test failed: Wanted to match 1 intents, actually matched 0 intents

Tags: java, android, junit, android-espresso

I am working in Android studio and am trying to test if a Button click launches a new Activity. In the emulator the Activity is clearly launched, but i keep getting Exceptions; for any button i test which launches a new Activity.
I tried just to check for an existing view in the new Activity but that did not work aswell.

The Code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mainActivityActivityTestRule  =   
        new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class);
    private MainActivity mainActivity = null;

   @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mainActivity = mainActivityActivityTestRule.getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void checklogin() throws Exception {
        onView(withId(R.id.loginbutton))
                .perform(click());

        Intents.init();
        intended(hasComponent(LoginActivity.class.getName()));
        Intents.release();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        mainActivity = null;
    }
}
```

The Stacktrace:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

IntentMatcher: has component: has component with: class name: is "swp.app.LoginActivity" package name: an instance of java.lang.String short class name: an instance of java.lang.String

Matched intents:[]

Recorded intents:[]
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:88)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:51)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:314)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:297)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended(Intents.java:188)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended(Intents.java:169)
at swp.app.MainActivityTest.checklogin(MainActivityTest.java:66)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:527)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

IntentMatcher: has component: has component with: class name: is "swp.app.LoginActivity" package name: an instance of java.lang.String short class name: an instance of java.lang.String

Matched intents:[]

Recorded intents:[]
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.VerificationModes$Times.verify(VerificationModes.java:80)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalIntended(Intents.java:316)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents$2.check(Intents.java:192)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAssertion.check(ViewInteraction.java:415)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:279)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:265)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: I'm having this same issue when running on API 28.  With API 27, the test passes.

Comment: What is the solution?  I am facing the same situation

Comment: Intents.init() has to be called before the click action.